# html - placing tables in destination places

Tags: html

I can't get right positions for my tables. I have code like this:

```
<div style="width: 1270px;">
  <div>
   <table style="float:left>
    <tr><td>something1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>something2</td></tr>
   </table>
   <img src="some_sorce">
   <table style="float:left>
    <tr><td>something3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>something4</td></tr>
   </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

And I have two problems:
First I want tables to be placed in bottom of containing div. I try some kind of "vertical-align" in some places but it fail for me. Secoundly i want the image to be in center of div, "text-align: center" don't do the trick. Could someone help me anyhow?

Comment: http://phrogz.net/css/vertical-align/index.html. CSS is absolutely moronic when it comes to controlling vertical alignment. The CSS folks need to come out of their basement ivory towers and see what the real world is like.

Comment: I don't understand vertical-align good. One time it seems to working like I expect, nut next time it works different. I will read what Yuo give me to read. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
<table>
<img src="some_sorce">
```

it should be:

```
</table>
<img src="some_sorce">
```

And by default images have display: inline attribute so You need to do something like:

```
<img src="some_sorce" style="display: block">
```

to center image

Comment: Sorry. My mistake when writing code here. Stone me to death for that ;/

Comment: or just `style="margin: 0 auto"`.

Comment: style="margin: 0 auto" didn't working when I put it in containing img div, didn't work if I put it as style to img.. :/